# Make TalkBack read button content description programmatically

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a button with 2 states, start and stop. In accessibility mode using TalkBack when the user double-taps the button I change the text of the button to stop so I must say to TalkBack in some way that this happened. I managed to achieve removing and readding focus to the button with following:

```
button.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);

// This works for the focus but doesn't make TalkBack speak.                           button.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null);

// Needed for TalkBack to speak.
button.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SELECT, null);
```

The problem with this is that TalkBack will only read the content description, but not say "double tap to activate" which gets read when you select the button manually.

Following didn't work:

```
button.requestFocus();
button.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
button.clearFocus();
```

`button.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED);`

Maybe somebody has a hint what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your clickListener use announceAccessibility

Comment: it's `v.announceForAccessibility`